# MySQL check unrelated data in 2 table

Tags: mysql

i have 2 simple tables.

table_1

```
id | name
===========
1  | Fulan
2  | Abu
3  | Buya
```

table_2

```
id_1 | id_2
===========
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 1
2    | 3
3    | 1
```

In table_2 data 2 connect to 3, but data 3 not connect to 2.

How to list table_1 where data 3 (in table_2) not connect with data 2 yet ?, so i will get name "Abu"

sorry if my question is confusing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all the names from table1 which are not paired with every other name from table1 (i.e. present as `id_2` in table2 for all other values of `id` in table1). You can do that with this query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_2 = t1.id) != 
      (SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM table1)
```

Output:

```
id  name
2   Abu
```

**Edit**

Based on clarification of the question, I've changed the query to list all the people who are not connected (where connected is defined as `table2.id_1` = person1 and `table2.id_2` = person2):

```
SELECT t1a.id, t1a.name, t1b.id, t1b.name
FROM table1 t1a
JOIN table1 t1b ON t1b.id != t1a.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id_1 = t1a.id AND t2.id_2 = t1b.id)
```

Output:

```
id  name    id  name
3   Buya    2   Abu
```

Comment: Thank before, but how do I find if only the relationship id: 3 only?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a cross self join (full outer) of `table_1` leaves a full list of the permutations. Then the left join on `table2` with a where criteria of `table_2.id_2 is null` finds rows in `table_2` that don't match the cross join. The final criteria is `t1.id!=t2.id` to eliminate the self match case.

```
select t1.id, t2.name from table_1 as t1
cross join table_1 as t2
left join table_2 on t1.id = id_1 and t2.id=id_2
where table_2.id_2 is null 
  and t1.id!=t2.id;
```